# Print information if I'm looking at a point

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location, gyroscope

I have some information in an Android App (Java).

- My point (my location)
- A point away from me
- x, y z, gyroscope information on change listener

This APP is running in a Smart Glasses. It's possible with both two points and my gyroscope decide if I'm looking to the away point? I would need to show the point information only if I be looking to the point.

Comment: Seems like more of an algorithm or even math question than a Java question, unless you're asking if there's some API that already does this calculation in which case it might be off-topic due to the recommendations rule.

Comment: @DavidConrad Should I change the tags?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry.